# How to print middle column with different string with screenshot

Tags: unix

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iz0p.jpg)

Hi, I have attached Unix terminal screenshot. I want column data under column header NAME.P. Please help.

Below is the sample:

```
Pid     Name of TTL         TOTAL
----- --------------------- -------
P36572 TTL rice sum         TOTAL3
P35621 TTL oil type sum     ToTAL6
P35612 TTL type of suasage  TOTAL7
```

I am looking for output in below format in different file of UNIX.

```
Name of TTL     
-------------------
TTL rice sum
TTL oil type sum
TTL type of suasage
```

Please help me to finish this. Really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: If you format your data in a nicer format, you could use `awk` pretty trivially.

Comment: The columns are not aligned. Do you want to `cut` from a fixed position, look for the largest word in the first column, remove first and last word for every line or are the columns delimited with tabs that get lost in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Use the cut command with start end end positions of the desired column

For example:

```
cut -c16-85 filename > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

this awk will print all fields exluding first and last.

```
awk '{ {for (i=2;i<NF;i++) x=x OFS $i} {print x;x=""} }  ' file
```